# Sonarqube app pod is not connecting with PostgreSQL DB pod when deploying to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubeadm, kubectl, sonarqube

I am trying to setup SonarQube in a Kubernetes cluster. The cluster was made using KubeADM in the AWS cloud. I have the following files for the setup.

1. Sonarqube App Deployment file
2. Sonarqube App Secrets file
3. Sonarqube-PostgreSQL Deployment file.
4. Sonarqube-PostgreSQL Persistent Volume and Volume Claim file
5. Sonarqube-PostgreSQL Secrets file.

Using these YAML files, I am able to bring the application up. I am using NodePort as the service type for the SonarQube App and it's working fine. Both the App and DB pods are running fine and I am even able to login to the SonarQube UI, configure my projects/data and do everything.

[image]

[image]

However, the problem is that, when I turn off the Servers and bring it back again after some time or delete the SonarQube App pod and when a new one spawns in it's place, the whole data is kind of lost.

I can also see that the PostgreSQL DB is ready to accept connections, however the App pod isnt supplying anything.

[image]

Seems that the data is being stored in the App pod itself and when something happens to it, the whole data is lost. So, when I delete the App pod and try to access the UI one more time, this is what I am getting.
[image]

Literally all the data is flushed.

The following are the YAML files that I was using:

**sonarqube-app.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: sonarqube
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarqube
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sonarqube
        image: sonarqube:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
            value: "10.107.194.222" # update this to reflect your IP 
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres-db-credentials
                key: user
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres-db-credentials
                key: password
          - name: POSTGRES_NAME
            value: 'postgres'
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: jdbc:postgres://$(POSTGRES_USER):$(POSTGRES_PASSWORD)@postgresql:5432/$(POSTGRES_NAME)
          - name: SECRET_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: sonarqube-secret-key
                key: secret_key    

        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresql-volume-mount
      volumes:
      - name: postgresql-volume-mount
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-service
  namespace: sonarqube 
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: sonarqube
```

**postgres-deployment.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgresql
  namespace: sonarqube 
  labels:
    app: postgres-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres-db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres-db
        tier: postgreSQL
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresql
          image: postgres:10.3
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
          env:
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres-db-credentials
                key: user
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres-db-credentials
                key: password
          - name: POSTGRES_NAME
            value: 'postgres'
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresql-volume-mount
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
      volumes:
      - name: postgresql-volume-mount
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pv-claim
      tolerations:
      - key: "blue"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "true"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgresql
  namespace: sonarqube
  labels:
    app: postgres-db
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.107.194.222
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: postgres-db
    tier: postgreSQL
```

**pv-pvc.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  namespace: sonarqube 
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 200M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: postgres-db
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  namespace: sonarqube
spec: 
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources: 
    requests: 
      storage: 100M
  storageClassName: manual
```

So, how can I get the App Pod to connect to the DB pod and also use PVC and PV as a means of storage of data?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the container incorrectly.

The sonarqube and postgres deployment are both referencing the same PVC, which cannot work. Only postgres needs it, as the [sonarqube container only comes with an embedded H2 DB](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/) and is supposed to use the postgres deployment.

Add a service to your postgres deployment and use the cluster DNS name in the JDBC URL. [Here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/)'s the reference for postgres.

Adhere to the documentation about [running SonarQube in a container](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/#header-4).

The environment variables for the DB connection are supposed to be:

```
    -e SONAR_JDBC_URL=... \
    -e SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME=... \
    -e SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD=...
```

You need those variables only on the container connecting to postgres, i.e. the sonarqube container.

Comment: Should I be adding these three env variables in both the deployment yaml files?

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed?

Comment: And what would the 'SONAR_JDBC_URL' be? Any particular syntax?